# Dark mode for CS.SE

Tags: feature-request

Following [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390761/colors-update-a-more-detailed-look), and in particular :

> - We will not be updating any individual site themes

I wondered if it would be possible to update cs.stackexchange's color themes to add a dark mode. I am not aware of the right process of doing so but I would very much like if this was possible (and I hope I am not the only one).

I think it would be ok to use the exact same theme as Stack Overflow, if possible.